# How to find the colour of main object in an fixed sized image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

My aim is to find the color of main object in a frame/image. In my case image is always of same type. For example *News reporter(human) in Forest or News reporter in Animal farm*.The position of news reporter is also same.What is the simple solution to find out the dominant colour of the main object(News Reporter)

Any help is welcome.Thanks

**EDIT Code added**

```
import cv2
from collections import namedtuple
from math import sqrt
import random
import webcolors


try:
 import Image
except ImportError:
 from PIL import Image

Point = namedtuple('Point', ('coords', 'n', 'ct'))
Cluster = namedtuple('Cluster', ('points', 'center', 'n'))

def get_points(img):
 points = []
 w, h = img.size
 for count, color in img.getcolors(w * h):
    points.append(Point(color, 3, count))
 return points

 rtoh = lambda rgb: '#%s' % ''.join(('%02x' % p for p in rgb))

def colorz(filename, n=3):
 img = Image.open(filename)
 img.thumbnail((200, 200))
 w, h = img.size

 points = get_points(img)
 clusters = kmeans(points, n, 1)
 rgbs = [map(int, c.center.coords) for c in clusters]
 return map(rtoh, rgbs)

def euclidean(p1, p2):
  return sqrt(sum([
  (p1.coords[i] - p2.coords[i]) ** 2 for i in range(p1.n)
 ]))

 def calculate_center(points, n):
  vals = [0.0 for i in range(n)]
  plen = 0
  for p in points:
    plen += p.ct
    for i in range(n):
        vals[i] += (p.coords[i] * p.ct)
   return Point([(v / plen) for v in vals], n, 1)

def kmeans(points, k, min_diff):
 clusters = [Cluster([p], p, p.n) for p in random.sample(points, k)]

 while 1:
   plists = [[] for i in range(k)]

   for p in points:
        smallest_distance = float('Inf')
        for i in range(k):
            distance = euclidean(p, clusters[i].center)
            if distance < smallest_distance:
                smallest_distance = distance
                idx = i
        plists[idx].append(p)

    diff = 0
    for i in range(k):
        old = clusters[i]
        center = calculate_center(plists[i], old.n)
        new = Cluster(plists[i], center, old.n)
        clusters[i] = new
        diff = max(diff, euclidean(old.center, new.center))

    if diff < min_diff:
        break

 return clusters

def main():

 img = cv2.imread('d:/Emmanu/project-data/b1.jpg')
 res=cv2.resize(img,(400,300))
 crop_img = res[100:200, 150:250]
 cv2.imwrite("d:/Emmanu/project-data/color-test.jpg", crop_img)
 g= colorz('d:/Emmanu/project-data/color-test.jpg',1)
 k=g[0]
 print k
 f=webcolors.hex_to_rgb(k)
 print webcolors.rgb_to_name(f, spec='css3')

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

The problem is this returns the major color in the whole image not the main object

Comment: @tfv I have edited.But this code gives me the major colour in the whole image not the objects colour.If news reporter wearing red dress and he is in forest.It will give green(Hex).

Comment: Define your problem as much formally as you can. The terms "main object" and "major colour" are defined loosely. Assuming that your "main object"
is the foreground, you can use opencv [background-subtraction](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0) and then apply your similar code as yours on the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your taking the colour of whole image,in most cases you will get wrong answer since background is more.If your image size is fixed and you are sure about object's position The most simple solution is Crop the image at where you expect the object.In most cases it will work.

In order to crop

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("'d:/Emmanu/project-data/b1.jpg'")
crop_img = img[200:400, 100:300] # Crop from x, y, w, h -> 100, 200, 300, 400
# NOTE: its img[y: y + h, x: x + w] and *not* img[x: x + w, y: y + h]
cv2.imshow("cropped", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Now give this crop_image as input to your code.And in most cases it will give correct solution.There is nothing more simple that this.I think this will help.